# PHP: Can't access parent class variables

Tags: php

I am trying to access the variables from the parent class as shown below:

```
 //PARENT CLASS
class InfoString{
    private $username = "JOE";

    public function _construct(){}

    protected function get_username(){
        return $this->username;
    }         
}


class Service extends InfoString{
    //this class should now inherit the variables in InfoString, right??
    public function _construct(){}

    public function hello_username(){
        echo "HELLO! ". parent::get_username(); 
    }
}
```

and I call the class like so:

```
$a = new Service();
$a->hello_username(); //prints nothing, instead of the username
```

Instead of getting "HELLO! JOE", I get an empty string. What am I doing wrong here?

Also, suppose the class 'InfoString' will contain configuration parameters - is it a good idea to extend this class, or what would be the proper implementation to get the config variables from, say class 'InfoString' into another class???

Thanks.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/wqiKSF

Comment: No, Its correct, make sure where you have  write your code. Seems There are no any errors.

Comment: Didn't find any wrong with your code. Its run very well in my server and print the desire output.

Comment: Must be something else in my code then. I ll double check. What about my question on using config file as parent class? Is this good OOP design or not?

Comment: @J.J. i think i'm not good. Hope you are well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just extending `InfoString`, so you can just use `$this->get_username();` and it will work fine. `::` is for calling static methods.

Also, you'd get an error if you'd increase your error level. Call `error_reporting(E_ALL)`; this will give you clues to solve similar issues in the future.